# Override default value of inherited model fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model structure along the lines of:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    STORE_TYPE = (
        ('I', 'Ice Cream'),
        ('H', 'Hardware'),
    ) 
    retailer_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STORE_TYPE)
    ...

class HardwareStore(Store):
        hammers_stocked = models.BooleanField()
```

I'd like to set retailer_type to H by default when I create a HardwareStore() object. Is it possible to set a default value on this field within the HardwareStore class?

Comment: HardwareStore inherits from `Retailer` or from `Store`?

Comment: sorry - it inherits from Store. Edited to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a elegant solution may be write code in [post_init](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) signal or overwriting init method to set default value. Procedure may be check if it is a new model or existing one (checking instance pk) and set your property to default value in right cases.

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's your answer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted), django doesn't permit that by default, if the field you're trying to override is a "Field" type. I think that if retailer_type was a base type (say a string) you could do that easily, since python allows this. Django, on the other hand, for its own datatypes, doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, try it

```
class Store(models.Model):
    STORE_TYPE = (
        ('I', 'Ice Cream'),
        ('H', 'Hardware'),
    )
    STORE_TYPE_DEFAULT = lambda: None

    retailer_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STORE_TYPE, default=STORE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
    ...

class HardwareStore(Store):
    STORE_TYPE_DEFAULT = lambda: 'H'

    hammers_stocked = models.BooleanField()
```

But why do you need `STORE_TYPE` anyway? You can use `isinstance(obj, HardwareStore)` or `hasttr(obj, 'hammers_stocked')` to check the type of the store.